# cost of partitioning in quicksort

Tags: algorithm, analysis, quicksort

[image]

In the above relation in the analysis  of quicksort(courtesy sedgewick's algorithms 4), the cost of partitioning is given as N+1 .Can someone explain this? Does this mean N+1 compares?

(I tried a similar question  in stackexchange but to no avail)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, on average the partitioning requires n+1 compares.  (Actually n+1-(1/n))

http://users.encs.concordia.ca/~chvatal/notes/qs.pdf